# The Best way to insert a range of consecutive integers without boost::counting_iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, containers, std

What's the Best way to insert a range of consecutive integers without boost::counting_iterator.[c++]

```
    // Insert 1 to 9
    set<long> set1.insert(boost::counting_iterator<int>(1)
                          ,boost::counting_iterator<int>(10))
```

Comment: Your code works. What else you want ? Apart from that you can just loop through and insert.

Comment: it works, but I want to do with out boost library.

Answer (score 1):

A `for` loop across the range calling `insert` works just fine and keeps the code simple to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```
std::set<long> s;
long l = 0;
std::generate_n(std::inserter(s, s.end()), 9, [&]{ return ++l; });
```

or the simple loop:

```
std::set<long> s;
for (long i = 1; i != 10; ++i) {
    s.insert(i);
}
```

Comment: thank you jarod but,  is it more faster than or similar to simple loop insertion with position hint ?

Comment: @joejo: the `generated_n` method requires a 'hint', so it is equivalent to an insertion loop with hint. Note though that the hint would be wrong in most cases (`s.end()` is not recomputed each time).